# How to Change or Replace array characters in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, curl

I tried to get username and password from client in the login form with CURL and Post to my webserver. my code below(Used in Qt):

```
int maint() {
    // ...

    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    std::string readBuffer;

    char username[] = "Username=Admin&Password=12781278";

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    /* get a curl handle */
    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if (curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.mywebsite.com/app/Test.php");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, username);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteCallback);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &readBuffer);
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        // Check for errors
        if (res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(
                stderr,
                "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res)
            );

        //always cleanup
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

I posted fields data with line:

```
char username[] = "Username=Admin&Password=12781278";
```

I want to get Username And Password from client input. how to replace 'Admin' username and '12781278' password with client input? i have 2 line edit for inputs.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with Qt? I don't see a single Qt API in use here.

Answer (score 0):

mystring.replace("/","\\");
The compiler uses \ as an escape character in strings (for things like \t, \n or \r) so that \ is actually turned into . If you need two backslashes, you need to start with four.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood your question well, but you could try something like this:

```
char username[] = "Username=Admin&Password=12781278";
QString un = QString(username);

// User Input
QString name = "myUsername"; // Read your username QLineEdit text here and store it in a QString
QString password = "myPassword"; // Read your password QLineEdit text here and store it in a QString

un.replace("Admin", name);
un.replace("12781278", password);
```